# How do i load a javascript file dependency in partial on Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js

I'm building a SPA with AngularJS.

How can I load a javascript file as a dependency, but this dependency can not be declared in the head tag of index.html because of the conflict with another dependency of a partial one, ie I need to inject the dependency when the partial is invoked and when I leave from this partial and to another, I need this dependence to be removed.

The dependency is:

```
<script src="/geodera/js/validatorsignup.js"></script>
```

I have index.html as layout, signup.html as partial as needed of this dependency, and UserCtrl.js as controller of that partial.

If my question was not clear, I apologize, because I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). No such thing as removing a dependency once it has been included. Need to figure out what the actual conflict is or use alternate approach to doing whatever the validatorsignup does

Comment: could you use an import at the top of your UserCtrl.js controller? Or is UserCtrl.js the depenency?

Comment: Yes for sure, I am currently using document.body.appendChild to do this injection via controller, but once I access partial and the dependence is loaded, when I navigate to another, that dependency remains loaded and conflict with the other is injected from another partial.

Comment: are you using webpack in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `import` at the top of your UserCtrl.js controller to include the dependency for that controller only.

```
import ValidatorSignup from '/geodera/js/validatorsignup.js';
```

Then you can use the dependency under the variable name `ValidatorSignup`

Comment: Hey George, but with this, /geodera/js/validatorsignup.js is loaded on view render or o need call ValidatorSignup on view ?

Comment: it will be loaded, and accessible, whenever the UserCtrl controller is used; and only accessible from within that controller. So no risk of clashes.